# Asp.NET gridview showing delete option to the latest row only.And same must be able to view on selected index change of radio button with data fill

Tags: asp.net

Actually I'm using GridView for fixed and percentage based commission and I'm hiding same on selected index change of radio button.

On page load I'm showing only delete option at latest row only which work properly. The problem comes when I'm trying to change the selected Index of the commission based radio button and at the same time binding data to the GridView from database accordingly.

```
public void LoadGrid(){
    try {
        DataTable DtLoadAgentCommission = new DataTable();
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("RowNumber");
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("MinCount");
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("MaxCount");

        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("AgentWiseCommission");
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("FixedAmount");
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("CommissionType");
        DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("CommissionDescription");

        DataRow dr = DtLoadAgentCommission.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = "1";
        dr["MinCount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["MaxCount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["CommissionType"] = string.Empty;
        dr["AgentWiseCommission"] = string.Empty;
        dr["FixedAmount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["CommissionDescription"] = string.Empty;

        DtLoadAgentCommission.Rows.Add(dr);

        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = DtLoadAgentCommission;
        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();
        ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = DtLoadAgentCommission;

    } catch (Exception Ex) {

        _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    try {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            RowIndexFromGV = RowIndexFromGV + 1;
            TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
            TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtMaxCount");
            DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
            TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtInterest");
            TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
            Label lblcommissiontypeID = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblcommissiontypeID");
            LinkButton btnRemoveAgentCommission = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("btnRemoveAgentCommission");

            string checkpostrowindex = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfremovecommIDs.Value)) {
                int removedId = Convert.ToInt32(hdfremovecommIDs.Value) - 1;

                if (removedId.ToString().Equals(checkpostrowindex)) {

                    btnRemoveAgentCommission.Visible = true;
                }
            } else
            if (RowsCountFromGV == RowIndexFromGV) {
                btnRemoveAgentCommission.Visible = true;
            }

            if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue == "1") {
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = true;
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", string.Format("alert('Commission slab can be change only on 1st Date of month.')"), true);

            } else {
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = true;
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = false;
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", string.Format("alert('Commission slab can be change only on 1st Date of month.')"), true);


            }
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

protected void rbtnFixedAmountTab1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {

        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"])) {
            fillAgentCommisionData();
            if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("1")) {

                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = true;

            } else if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("2")) {
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = true;
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = false;

            }
        } else {
            if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedIndex == 1) {


            } else {

            }

            string DateValue = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]);
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Commission type can be change only on " + DateValue + " Date of month.  " + "');</script>");


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            AppLog.ErrorLog(sender, ex);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(string), "msg", "alert('Alarm: Contact system administrator');", true);
        }
    }
}

public void fillAgentCommisionData() {
    try {

        DataTable AgentCommisionConfiguration = new DataTable();
        AgentCommisionConfiguration = MobilePortalProcess.GetAgentCommisionConfigurationDetails();

        if (AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count > 0) {
            if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("0") || rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("1") || rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("2")) {

            } else {
                RowsCountFromGV = AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count;
                rbtnFixedAmountTab1.Items.FindByText(AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[0]["CommissionDescription"].ToString()).Selected = true;
            }

            grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = AgentCommisionConfiguration;
            grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();

            AgentCommissionType = AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[0]["CommissionDescription"].ToString();
            ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = AgentCommisionConfiguration;
        }

    } catch (Exception Ex) {

        _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
    }
}

private void SetPreviousAgentCommission() {
    try {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] != null) {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable) ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
                    Label RowNumber = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                    TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                    TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                    DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                    TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                    TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");

                    RowNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1);

                    txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MinCount"].ToString();
                    txtMaxCount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MaxCount"].ToString();
                    ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["CommissionType"].ToString();
                    txtInterest.Text = dt.Rows[i]["AgentWiseCommission"].ToString();
                    txtFixedAmount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["FixedAmount"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception Ex) {

        _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    try {
        string _CommandName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandName);
        if (_CommandName == "AddCommssionDetails") {

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "Confirm()", true);
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

            if (confirmValue == "Yes") {
                // if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("dd"))
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"])) {
                    int rowindex = 0;
                    if (ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] != null) {
                        DataTable dtAgentComission = (DataTable) ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];
                        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                        if (grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count > 0) {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count; i++) {
                                Label RowNumber = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                                TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                                TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                                DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                                TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                                TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
                                Label lblCommissionType = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[6].FindControl("lblCommissionType");
                                Label lblCommissionTypeName = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[7].FindControl("lblCommissionTypeName");

                                drCurrentRow = dtAgentComission.NewRow();
                                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MinCount"] = txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MaxCount"] = txtMaxCount.Text;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["AgentWiseCommission"] = txtInterest.Text;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["FixedAmount"] = txtFixedAmount.Text;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = lblCommissionType.Text;
                                dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionDescription"] = lblCommissionTypeName.Text;
                                rowindex++;
                            }
                            dtAgentComission.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                            ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = dtAgentComission;
                            grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = dtAgentComission;
                            grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();
                        }
                        SetPreviousAgentCommission();
                    }
                } else {

                    string DateValue = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]);
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Commission slab can be change only on " + DateValue + " Date of month.  " + "');</script>");
                }
            } else {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", string.Format("alert('You clicked Cancel.')"), true);
            }
        }
        if (_CommandName == "RemoveAgentCommission") {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "ConfirmOnCancel()", true);
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

            if (confirmValue == "Yes") {

                DataTable dtRemoveAgentComission = (DataTable) ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];

                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton) e.CommandSource;
                GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow) lnkBtn.Parent.Parent;
                int rowindex = myRow.RowIndex;
                hdfremovecommIDs.Value = rowindex.ToString();
                int rowIndex1 = 0;
                if (dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Count > 1) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count; i++) {
                        Label RowNumber = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                        TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                        TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                        DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                        TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                        TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
                        Label lblCommissionType = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[6].FindControl("lblCommissionType");
                        Label lblCommissionTypeName = (Label) grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[7].FindControl("lblCommissionTypeName");

                        drCurrentRow = dtRemoveAgentComission.NewRow();
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MinCount"] = txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text;
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MaxCount"] = txtMaxCount.Text;
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue.ToString();
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["AgentWiseCommission"] = txtInterest.Text;
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["FixedAmount"] = txtFixedAmount.Text;
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = lblCommissionType.Text;
                        dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionDescription"] = lblCommissionTypeName.Text;
                        rowIndex1++;

                    }

                    //  dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Remove(dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[rowindex]);

                    ViewState["VW_gvAgentcommission"] = dtRemoveAgentComission;

                    //RowsCountFromGV = dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Count;
                    // RowIndexFromGV = dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Count;
                    grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = dtRemoveAgentComission;
                    grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();
                }

            } else {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", string.Format("alert('You clicked Cancel.')"), true);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception Ex) {

        _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
    }
}
```

ASPX design shown below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RowNumber" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" ShowFooter="true" class="display table-responsive" Style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); width: 100%;" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" border="0" EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowDataBound="grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowCommand">
        <%--OnRowCreated="grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowCreated"--%>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl.No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="RowNumber" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Min Count">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFixedAmountTabMinCount" runat="server" MaxLength="33" PlaceHolder="Enter Minimum Count" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("MinCount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtInterest_FilteredtxtFixedAmountTabMinCount" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtFixedAmountTabMinCount" FilterType="Numbers,Custom" FilterMode="ValidChars" ValidChars=" .">
                    </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Max Count">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaxCount" MaxLength="13" PlaceHolder="Enter Maximum Count" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("MaxCount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtInterest_FilteredtxtMaxCount" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtMaxCount" FilterType="Numbers,Custom" FilterMode="ValidChars" ValidChars=" .">
                    </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commssion Type" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcommissiontypeID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CommissionType") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCommissionType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommissionType_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Fixed Amount"> </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Percentage Wise"> </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Interest">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInterest" MaxLength="13" PlaceHolder="Enter Interest Rate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Eval("AgentWiseCommission") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtInterest_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtInterest" FilterType="Numbers,Custom" FilterMode="ValidChars" ValidChars=" .">
                    </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="25%" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Global Amount">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFixedAmount" MaxLength="13" PlaceHolder="Enter Fixed Amount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="94%" Text='<%#Eval("FixedAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtInterest_FilteredtxtFixedAmount" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtFixedAmount" FilterType="Numbers,Custom" FilterMode="ValidChars" ValidChars=" .">
                    </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="25%" Wrap="false" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commision Type" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCommissionType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CommissionType")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commision Type Name" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCommissionTypeName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CommissionDescription")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveAgentCommission" runat="server" CommandName="RemoveAgentCommission" OnClientClick="ConfirmOnCancel()" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RowNumber") %>' Visible="false">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="../Images/minus.png" ID="imgRemoveTeamEmployee" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to delete this row" Style="cursor: pointer;" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="RemoveTeamEmployeeSubTask" class="tableActionButton" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="4%" Wrap="false" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddSubTask" runat="server" CommandName="AddCommssionDetails" OnClientClick="Confirm()" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RowNumber") %>'>
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl="../Images/plus.png" ID="imgAddEmp" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to add new Row" Style="cursor: pointer;" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="AddSubTask" class="tableActionButton" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please make sure the code is formatted properly before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ClassFiles.clsCommandFunctions _clsCommandFunctions = new ClassFiles.clsCommandFunctions();
        DataTable GetCommissionAgent = null;
        string AgentCode = string.Empty;
        string CommisionType = string.Empty;
        string ViewCommisionType = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMinCount1 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMaxCount1 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionAmount1 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionPercentage1 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMinCount2 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMaxCount2 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionAmount2 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionPercentage2 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMinCount3 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionMaxCount3 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionAmount3 = string.Empty;
        string CommisionPercentage3 = string.Empty;
        DataTable InsertOrUpdateAgentCommission = null;
        DataTable FixedUpdateAgentCommission = null;
        DataTable RemoveAgentWiseCommission = null;
        DataSet ViewAgentCommissionData = new DataSet();
        string NewAgentcode = string.Empty;
        string ViewAgentCode = string.Empty;
        string EditAgentCode = string.Empty;
        string Type = string.Empty;
        int Status = -1;
        // start of Initialization of variable for maintaining adding and removing row index
        int RowsCountFromGV = 0;
        int RowIndexFromGV = -1;
        // End of Initialization of variable for maintaining adding and removing row index
        DataTable GetViewCommissionDetails = null;

        DataSet ViewAgentData = new DataSet();
        DataTable InsertUpdateAgentCommission = null;
        string CommissionDescription = string.Empty;






if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (Session["Username"] != null)
                    {
                        LoadGrid();
                        fillAgentCommisionData();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/frmLogin.aspx");
                    }
                }

    enter code here
public void LoadGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable DtLoadAgentCommission = new DataTable();
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("RowNumber");
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("MinCount");
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("MaxCount");

                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("AgentWiseCommission");
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("FixedAmount");
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("CommissionType");
                DtLoadAgentCommission.Columns.Add("CommissionDescription");

                DataRow dr = DtLoadAgentCommission.NewRow();
                dr["RowNumber"] = "1";
                dr["MinCount"] = string.Empty;
                dr["MaxCount"] = string.Empty;
                dr["CommissionType"] = string.Empty;
                dr["AgentWiseCommission"] = string.Empty;
                dr["FixedAmount"] = string.Empty;
                dr["CommissionDescription"] = string.Empty;

                DtLoadAgentCommission.Rows.Add(dr);

                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = DtLoadAgentCommission;
                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();
                ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = DtLoadAgentCommission;




            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occurred :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    enter code here

 public void fillAgentCommisionData()
        {
            try
            {

                DataTable AgentCommisionConfiguration = new DataTable();
                AgentCommisionConfiguration = MobilePortalProcess.GetAgentCommisionConfigurationDetails();


                RowsCountFromGV = AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count; // To store total count of records for showing remove row option
                if (AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("0") || rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("1") || rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue.Equals("2"))
                    {
                        LoadGrid();
                        hdfremovecommIDs.Value = string.Empty;
                        HiddenFieldForChange.Value = string.Empty;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        rbtnFixedAmountTab1.Items.FindByText(AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[0]["CommissionDescription"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                    }



                    grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = AgentCommisionConfiguration;
                    grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();

                    AgentCommissionType = AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[0]["CommissionDescription"].ToString();
                    ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = AgentCommisionConfiguration;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    enter code here
 protected void rbtnFixedAmountTab1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]))
                {
                    fillAgentCommisionData();
                    if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = true;

                    }

                    else if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                    {
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = true;
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                    {
                        rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue = "1";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue = "2";

                    }



                    string DateValue = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "InvalidArgs", "alert('Commission type can be change only on " + DateValue + " Date of month.');", true);
                }
                }
                ModalPopupBranchWiseTotalAllocatedPopup.Show();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppLog.ErrorLog(sender, ex);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(string), "msg", "alert('Alarm: Contact system administrator');", true);
            }
        }

 protected void grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    RowIndexFromGV = Convert.ToInt32(RowIndexFromGV + 1); // For storing Initial index of gridId

                    TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                    TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                    DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                    TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtInterest");
                    TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
                    Label lblcommissiontypeID = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblcommissiontypeID");
                    LinkButton btnRemoveAgentCommission = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnRemoveAgentCommission");

                    DataTable AgentCommisionConfiguration = new DataTable();
                    AgentCommisionConfiguration = MobilePortalProcess.GetEditedAgentWiseCommisionDetails(AgentCode);

                    RowsCountFromGV = AgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count;

                    string checkpostrowindex = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfremovecommIDs.Value))
                    {
                        // This used for storing Index of after removing new row
                        int removedId = Convert.ToInt32(hdfremovecommIDs.Value) - 1;

                        if (removedId.ToString().Equals(checkpostrowindex))
                        {

                            btnRemoveAgentCommission.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HiddenFieldForChange.Value))
                    {
                        int ViewAddedRow = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldForChange.Value) - 1;

                        if (ViewAddedRow.ToString().Equals(checkpostrowindex))
                        {
                            btnRemoveAgentCommission.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }


                    else
                        if (RowsCountFromGV == RowIndexFromGV)
                        {
                            //For checking rowcount of gridview from pageload and after selected index change of radio button
                            btnRemoveAgentCommission.Visible = true;
                        }



                    if (rbtnFixedAmountTab1.SelectedValue == "1")
                    {

                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[4].Visible = true;
                        grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Columns[5].Visible = false;

                    }



                }
                ModalPopupBranchWiseTotalAllocatedPopup.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }

  private void SetPreviousAgentCommission()
        {
            try
            {
                int rowIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Label RowNumber = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                            TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                            TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                            DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                            TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                            TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");


                            RowNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1);

                            txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MinCount"].ToString();
                            txtMaxCount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MaxCount"].ToString();
                            ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["CommissionType"].ToString();
                            txtInterest.Text = dt.Rows[i]["AgentWiseCommission"].ToString();
                            txtFixedAmount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["FixedAmount"].ToString();

                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }


  protected void grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string _CommandName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandName);

                if (_CommandName == "AddCommssionDetails")
                {
                    if (confirmValue.Value.ToString().Trim().Equals("Yes"))
                    {
                        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]))
                        {
                            int rowindex = 0;
                            if (ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] != null)
                            {
                                DataTable dtAgentComission = (DataTable)ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];
                                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                                if (grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    int rowindex2 = grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count - 1;

                                    for (int i = 1; i <= grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        Label RowNumber = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                                        TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                                        TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                                        DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                                        TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                                        TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
                                        Label lblCommissionType = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[6].FindControl("lblCommissionType");
                                        Label lblCommissionTypeName = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[7].FindControl("lblCommissionTypeName");

                                        drCurrentRow = dtAgentComission.NewRow();
                                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MinCount"] = txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MaxCount"] = txtMaxCount.Text;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["AgentWiseCommission"] = txtInterest.Text;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["FixedAmount"] = txtFixedAmount.Text;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = lblCommissionType.Text;
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionDescription"] = lblCommissionTypeName.Text;
                                        rowindex++;
                                    }

                                    if ((dtAgentComission.Rows[rowindex2]["MinCount"] != "") && (dtAgentComission.Rows[rowindex2]["MaxCount"] != "") && ((dtAgentComission.Rows[rowindex2]["AgentWiseCommission"] != "") || (dtAgentComission.Rows[rowindex2]["FixedAmount"] != "")) || (dtAgentComission.Rows[rowindex2]["CommissionType"] != ""))
                                    {
                                        dtAgentComission.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Kindly filled records and click on save button first to add new row.');", true);
                                    }
ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"] = dtAgentComission;
                                    //start of region for hidden field for storing row id value 
                                    int CurrentTotalRowCount = dtAgentComission.Rows.Count;
                                    HiddenFieldForChange.Value = CurrentTotalRowCount.ToString();
     //End of region for  hidden field for storing row id value                      grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = dtAgentComission;
                                    grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();
                                }
                                SetPreviousAgentCommission();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            string DateValue = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]);
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "InvalidArgs", "alert('Commission type can be change only on " + DateValue + " Date of month.');", true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('You clicked Cancel.');", true);

                    }
                    ModalPopupBranchWiseTotalAllocatedPopup.Show();
                }
                if (_CommandName == "RemoveAgentCommission")
                {
                    if (confirmValue.Value.ToString().Trim().Equals("Yes"))
                    {
                        if (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") == Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]))
                        {
                            DataTable dtRemoveAgentComission = (DataTable)ViewState["ViewAgentCommission"];
                            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                            LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
                            GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)lnkBtn.Parent.Parent;
                            int rowindex = myRow.RowIndex;
                            hdfremovecommIDs.Value = rowindex.ToString(); // For storing latest index of row for showing row removal option to the latest row.
                            int rowIndex1 = 0;

                            if (dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Count > 1)
                            {
                                for (int i = 1; i <= grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    Label RowNumber = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[1].FindControl("RowNumber");
                                    TextBox txtFixedAmountTabMinCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[1].FindControl("txtFixedAmountTabMinCount");
                                    TextBox txtMaxCount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[2].FindControl("txtMaxCount");
                                    DropDownList ddlCommissionType = (DropDownList)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("ddlCommissionType");
                                    TextBox txtInterest = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[4].FindControl("txtInterest");
                                    TextBox txtFixedAmount = (TextBox)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[5].FindControl("txtFixedAmount");
                                    Label lblCommissionType = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[6].FindControl("lblCommissionType");
                                    Label lblCommissionTypeName = (Label)grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows[rowindex].Cells[7].FindControl("lblCommissionTypeName");

                                    drCurrentRow = dtRemoveAgentComission.NewRow();
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MinCount"] = txtFixedAmountTabMinCount.Text;
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["MaxCount"] = txtMaxCount.Text;
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = ddlCommissionType.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["AgentWiseCommission"] = txtInterest.Text;
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["FixedAmount"] = txtFixedAmount.Text;
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionType"] = lblCommissionType.Text;
                                    dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[i - 1]["CommissionDescription"] = lblCommissionTypeName.Text;
                                    rowIndex1++;
                                }                          dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows.Remove(dtRemoveAgentComission.Rows[rowindex]);

                                ViewState["VW_gvAgentcommission"] = dtRemoveAgentComission;
                                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataSource = dtRemoveAgentComission;
                                grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.DataBind();

                                AgentCode = lblAgentCode.Text;

                                ViewAgentCommissionData = MobilePortalProcess.ViewEditAgentRangeWiseCommissionData(rowIndex1, AgentCode);
                                if (grvViewFixedAgentCommisionConfiguration.Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    if (ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0] != null)
                                    {
                                        if (ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            string AgentCodeData = string.Empty;
                                            string MiCount = string.Empty;
                                            string MaxCount = string.Empty;
                                            string CommissionType = string.Empty;
                                            string CommissionDescription = string.Empty;                                    MiCount = ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MinCount"].ToString();
                                            MaxCount = ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MaxCount"].ToString();
                                            string FixedAmount = ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FixedAmount"].ToString() == "" ? string.Empty : ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FixedAmount"].ToString();
                                            string AgentWiseCommission = ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AgentWiseCommission"].ToString() == "" ? string.Empty : ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AgentWiseCommission"].ToString();
                                            CommissionDescription = ViewAgentCommissionData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CommissionDescription"].ToString();               RemoveEditAgentWiseIndividualCommission(
                                             Convert.ToString(rowIndex1),
                                             MiCount, MaxCount, CommissionType, CommissionDescription, FixedAmount, AgentWiseCommission,
                                             Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]), AgentCode);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string DateValue = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartOfDate"]);
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "InvalidArgs", "alert('Commission type can be change only on " + DateValue + " Date of month.');", true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('You clicked Cancel.');", true);
                    }

                    ModalPopupBranchWiseTotalAllocatedPopup.Show();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
private void RemoveEditAgentWiseIndividualCommission(string RowIndex, string MinCount, string MaxCount, string CommissionTypeID, string CommissionDescription, string FixedAmount, string PercentageInterest, string CreatedBy, string AgentCodeData)
        {
            try
            {
                RemoveAgentWiseCommission = MobilePortalProcess.RemoveEditAgentWiseIndividualCommission(RowIndex, MinCount, MaxCount, CommissionTypeID, CommissionDescription, FixedAmount, PercentageInterest, CreatedBy, AgentCodeData);


                if (RemoveAgentWiseCommission.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(string), "msg", "alert('AgentWise Commission Slab Removed Successfully.');window.location='../AgencyBanking/AgentEditCommissionConfiguration.aspx';", true);   
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(string), "msg", "alert('Contact system administrator.');window.location='../AgencyBanking/AgentEditCommissionConfiguration.aspx';", true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            { _clsCommandFunctions.writeLog("Exception  Occured :\n ." + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
```